# active log in production mode ? it's a good idea or not?

Tags: node.js, production

in context of a nodejs backend applicaton ,In production mode, storing log (request/ response) its good idea or not ?

for example : using library like good

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kind it depends. Logs can be helpful, but sometimes is a hardwork to manage them and eventually find something useful when you really need, for example, a error stack. Also, it can use space in your hosting service if you don't have some cleaning or backup routine.

Futhermore, don't forget the `console.log`  is a blocking operation, that can be decrease the performance of the application when used in excess. Some libs makes it better, such [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) but doesn't avoid this.

If you want just to got more helpful error stacks when it happens, I sugest you take a look in [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com) . Is good service of crash report. Everything you need is just catch your errors and send to this service using the [library](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js).